# apt packages could not be installed... but the dependencies are there

Tags: apt, raspbian, dependencies

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but I'm new to working on a bare linux machine.  So I'm trying to install git on a raspberry pi.  When I run `sudo apt-get install git-all` I get errors telling me about missing dependencies... that are already installed.

Specifically, I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 glib-networking : Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas but it is not going to be installed
 libgoa-1.0-0b : Depends: libgoa-1.0-common (>= 3.30.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk-3-common : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not going to be installed or
                            gsettings-backend
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

"Ok," I thought to myself, "I'll just install the dependencies."

`sudo apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas`

```
gsettings-desktop-schemas is already the newest version (3.28.1-1).
gsettings-desktop-schemas set to manually installed.
```

???  Ok then, if the thing that glib-networking depends on is already installed, then I should be able to `sudo apt-get install glib-networking`

```
glib-networking is already the newest version (2.58.0-2+deb10u2).
glib-networking set to manually installed.
```

So, APT, let me get this straight.  You can't install git, because it depends on glib-networking, which in turn depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas, and you refuse for some unstated reason to install gsettings-desktop-schemas.  But, in fact, I **already have** both of those packages installed... huh???

The same is true of all of the dependencies.  I finally threw up my hands:

`sudo apt-get install glib-networking gsettings-desktop-schemas libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgtk-3-common dconf-gsettings-backend gsettings-backend`

```
Package gsettings-backend is a virtual package provided by:
  gconf-gsettings-backend 3.2.6-5
  dconf-gsettings-backend 0.30.1-2
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'gsettings-backend' has no installation candidate
```

`sudo apt-get install glib-networking gsettings-desktop-schemas libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgtk-3-common dconf-gsettings-backend`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dconf-gsettings-backend is already the newest version (0.30.1-2).
dconf-gsettings-backend set to manually installed.
glib-networking is already the newest version (2.58.0-2+deb10u2).
gsettings-desktop-schemas is already the newest version (3.28.1-1).
libgoa-1.0-0b is already the newest version (3.30.1-2).
libgoa-1.0-0b set to manually installed.
libgoa-1.0-common is already the newest version (3.30.1-2).
libgoa-1.0-common set to manually installed.
libgtk-3-common is already the newest version (3.24.5-1+rpt2).
libgtk-3-common set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I found [this prior SO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412190/dependency-problem-but-the-dependencies-are-installed) which suggests that this kind of behavior can be caused by a mismatch between raspberry pi OS versions.  But that doesn't seem to apply here: I'm on buster, and `apt-cache policy` produces:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,a=testing,n=buster,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main,b=armhf
     origin archive.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/rpi armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=rpi,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/non-free armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=non-free,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/contrib armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=contrib,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=main,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
Pinned packages:
```

I've also tried every random incantation to fix apt that I could find on the internet, including `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt update`,  `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, and `sudo apt-get -f install` --- none of which seem to make an iota of difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt install git` instead of `sudo apt install git-all`.

Answer (score 0):

The message from `apt` doesn't necessary mean that the packages are not installed. It means that, as a result of installation which you request, the packages cannot be installed. This can happen if some other dependencies of `git-all` want to remove the already installed packages because of conflicts. Try adding the packages which apt complains about and which you want to keep to your command for installation of `git-all`. It's better to add `-s` to simulate installation first. As [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612321/423679) shows, resolving dependencies when installing `git-all` can be too complicated for `apt` to handle automatically because it may choose wrong alternative dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt -f install`. This will fix all the missing dependencies. Then run `sudo apt-get install git-all` again.